# Exercise about counting 1 bits in an integer in C

Tags: c, bit, bitwise-operators

Exercise 2-9. In a two's complement number system, x &= (x-1) deletes the rightmost 1-bit in x.
Explain why. Use this observation to write a faster version of `bitcount`.

The `bitcount` function mentioned by the exercise is this:

```
/* bitcount:  count 1 bits in x */
int bitcount(unsigned x) {
    int b;
    for (b = 0; x != 0; x >>= 1)
        if (x & 01)
            b++;
    return b;
}
```

I kind of got why this happens intuitively but I couldn't find a more rigorous answer, here's the answer I came up with anyways:
*the reason behind this I guess is because when we subtract one we
change the position of the rightmost bit therefore when we bitwise AND x
with x-1 the rightmost 1 disappears because the rightmost 1 in x changed
its position in x - 1 because of substracting one
for example if x  = 1010
then x-1 = 1001
and when we bitwise AND them we get 1000
so the rightmost 1 in x disappeared*

And here's my implementation of this idea to write a shorter version of `bitcount`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bitcount(unsigned x);

int main() {
    int x, onebits;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    onebits = bitcount(x);
    printf("This integer contains %d one bits.", onebits);
    return 0;
}

int bitcount(unsigned x) {
    int b;
    for (b = 0; x != 0; x &= (x - 1))
        ++b;
    return b;
}
```

Can anyone correct me if I made any mistakes or provide a more rigorous answer than mine? Thanks! :)

This exercise is from the famous book *The C Programming Language by Ritchie and Kerninghan*

Comment: Use pen and paper to work with an example like `0x70` (`0b01110000`)... Watch the 3 set bits vanish one-by-one (no pun)... Work through some other examples... Reported as one of Kernigahn's contributions to algorithms..

Comment: yes I worked with pen and paper and that's why I could notice how this expression deletes the ones one by one.

Comment: "Use this observation to write a faster version of bitcount." Once upon a time this might have been true... maybe... I kind of doubt it was correct even when this ancient book was written. To begin with, faster versions of bit count do not iterate across all bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, but the explanation of why the operation works is not very rigorous.

A binary number can end with either `0` or `1`.

If it ends with `1`, subtracting 1 simply changes that to a `0`. When you AND this with the original number, all the other bits stay the same, and `1 & 0` becomes `0`. Since the last 1 bit was also the last bit, this removes the last 1 bit.

If it ends with `0`, subtracting 1 has to "borrow" from the next higher bit. If that bit is also `0`, it borrow from the next bit, and so on. All the low-order 0 bits get flipped to `1`, and when the borrowing ends the `1` bit is flipped to `0`. So if you start with `111000`, the borrowing and flipping results in `110111`. As you can see, all the low-order `0` bits turn to `1`, and the lowest `1` bit turns to `0`. When you AND these, the bits higher than the series of flipping and borrowing stay the same, while the lower bits all cancel out to `0`. The final result is that the lowest `1` bit is converted to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

> I kind of got why this happens intuitively but I couldn't find a more rigorous answer, here's the answer I came up with anyways: the reason behind this I guess is because when we subtract one we change the position of the rightmost bit therefore when we bitwise AND x with x-1 the rightmost 1 disappears because the rightmost 1 in x changed its position in x - 1 because of substracting one for example if x = 1010 then x-1 = 1001 and when we bitwise AND them we get 1000 so the rightmost 1 in x disappeared

In a two's complement numbering system, both signed and unsigned arithmetic work the same way  (the arithmetic is the same, the only difference being at which point the overflow or carry are detected), so a binary number can be represented as a string or ones and ceros in binary that, in general will end in 0 or more `0` bits at the right part.

if you subtract one to the number, and the number has zeros at the end, all those zeros will be converted into ones (making carry to propagate to the next digit), and finally, the last `1` bit will be changed to a zero, as a consequence of carry being propagated from the right.  Carry stops propagating as soon as it gets subtracted from the first one it encounters, so the result operation for any number you can have is that all the trailing zeros change into ones, and the last one (and only that last one) gets change into a 0.

```
100101011010100000
100101011010011111
            ^^^^^^  alll these bits change.
```

if you now bitwise and all those bits, you will see that all the *equal* bits get unchanged by the `&` operator, while the different ones get all zeroed (1 ^ 0 == 0 ^ 1 == 0)  this means that all zeros get unchanged, and the last `1` bit gets zeroed.  QED.  (you can check that if no zeros end the number, only the last one bit is changed into a zero)

On other side, this will accelerate the way you proceed because it immediately detects the `1` bits themselves and skips over the `0` bits.  For a number that has a small set of `1` bits will go faster.

There's another (faster) way of counting the `1` bits instead: You can consider your number as a set of 2 bit registers and extract the left bit of each (this can be done in parallel) right shift it and do a complete add to the right shift,  this will add in one shot all the pairs of bits together, giving a set of two bit numbers (with a range of 0..2, so it never overflows)
if you now repeat this, but considering the bits as groups of two bits and extending the accumulators from two to four bits, we can again add the numbers of pairs of bits togethers, and continue this until we have a full register of 32 bits (or 64, just with one more step) ending with the sum of all the 1 bits in the register:  This leads to the following (a bit obscure) but by far more efficient than your loop, which has a worse worst case when all ones have to be zeroed one by one.

```
uint64_t sum_of_bits(uint64_t n)
{
    n = ((n & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaULL) >>  1) + (n & 0x5555555555555555ULL);
    n = ((n & 0xccccccccccccccccULL) >>  2) + (n & 0x3333333333333333ULL);
    n = ((n & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0ULL) >>  4) + (n & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fULL);
    n = ((n & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00ULL) >>  8) + (n & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffULL);
    n = ((n & 0xffff0000ffff0000ULL) >> 16) + (n & 0x0000ffff0000ffffULL);
    n = ((n & 0xffffffff00000000ULL) >> 32) + (n & 0x00000000ffffffffULL);
    return n;
}
```

in this method you get profit of the parllel sums. and you go faster.

Comment: ((n & 0xffffffff00000000ULL) >> 32) = (n >> 32)

Comment: I wrote it that wary for uniformity (indeed I started copy/pasteing the lines six times to write them) Anyway, the compiler will encode it correctly (as  you post) once optimized.  My intention is to show how the algorithm is built, and not to get the completely optimized version.  Thanks for the point, anyway!! :)